# What problems could make an Applet run on Ubuntu, but not on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, firefox, ubuntu, applet

I have an Applet that I'm working on. The Applet is located on my server. If I access the Applet using Firefox on Ubuntu, the Applet works fine. If I access that same Applet from a windows pc using Chrome or Firefox, nothing happens. A gray block the size of the Applet appears and then the real program never loads into the browser. What problems could cause this?

I'm using JNLP to load the Applet through a basic .html page.

HTML File contents:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Applet</title>
    <script src="deployJava.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test App</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var attributes = {
            code : 'Jar',
            width: 640,
            height: 480
        };
        var parameters = {
            jnlp_href: 'name.jnlp'
        };
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I changed some values, like Jar and name, just because this stuff is for work. Thanks in advance again.

Comment: Paste the contents of the HTML file. You might be pointing to the jar file using a path that only makes sense from the Linux boxes perspective.

Comment: I added the HTML code. I changed a few sensitive values to different ones.